# Get first several only items of the array with fetch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, while-loop, fetch

How can I get only five items of an array set by a fetch function? I'm passing the function second  arrgument as a number = 5? and doing a while loop. But still getting the whole amount of the items in the array.
https://codesandbox.io/s/html-template-forked-izfjoc?file=/index.html

```js
people: [],
getAllProducts(searchInput, num = 5) {
            let i = 0
            while(i < num){
              fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((res) => {
                  this.people = res;
                });
                i++
              }
            },
```

Comment: `this.people.push(res)` instead?

Comment: i think you need to use res.slice(0,5) without using a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get only the first 5 items.

```js
people: [],
getAllProducts(searchInput, num = 5) {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
      // Set people to only a portion of the array, from index 0 to num
      this.people = res.slice(0, num);
    });
},
```

In your code, instead of adding a single item to the array in each iteration of the `while` loop, you were setting the `people` property to the entire response array.

Comment: Ok, and is there a way to implement it with an infinite scroll, and load up next 5 items later on scroll?